# Extract strings in R

Tags: r

Is there a way to extract specific strings in R sentence.
Example, I need only "test model" (What is there before 1st Commnents :). Is you see carefully, before "Commnents :", there is also "Comments are useful. " but I do not see. Just that what is there before 1st Commnents : is what I require

```
asd <- "Model : test modelComments : Comments are useful. Comments :"
```

Expected output

```
test model
```

Example 2

```
asd1 <- "Model : Example2Comments : Useful. Comments :"
```

Expected output

```
Example2
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
gsub(".*?: ([^:]*)Comments :.*", "\\1", asd)
# [1] "test model"
```

This grabs the non-colon values before the first "Comments :" appearance in the string. We capture the value and then replace the existing value with that matching group.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following which matches anything between two strings:

```r
asd <- "Model : test modelComments : Comments are useful. Comments :"
asd1 <- "Model : Example2Comments : Useful. Comments :"
library(stringr)
output <- str_match(asd, "Model : \\s*(.*?)\\s*Comments")
output[,2]
#> [1] "test model"
output1 <- str_match(asd1, "Model : \\s*(.*?)\\s*Comments")
output1[,2]
#> [1] "Example2"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>